# sed/awk/grep/perl... script to look for file content within files and if matched to change it to the content of another file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to find and replace inline svg code on single line HTML/JS generated files.

I see many examples of sed and/or awk scripts for matching the contents of a file within another file but I encounter two problems: either I can't figure out how to substitute the matched file by the contents of a 3rd file or the search is only valid if the entire line matches the file (the files being searched are single lined html with all the code glued together...).

to put it in simple pseudo-code, what I'm looking for is:

`IF oldImage.svg IS MATCHED IN file.html THEN REPLACE MATCHED TEXT BY newImage.svg`

I know that the whole svg file is being matched inside the html ones as I've run
`grep -wFf oldImage.svg file.html` with success.

Also, if the solution could be recursive for all files in subfolders that would be a great plus.

.

**UPDATE:**

Example as requested by @anubhava

oldImage.svg

```
<svg>old file graphics...</svg>
```

newImage.svg

```
<svg>great new graphics...</svg>
```

file.html (before script)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> example </title>
</head>
<body>
<svg>old file graphics...</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

file.html (after running the script)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> example </title>
</head>
<body>
<svg>great new graphics...</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

(bearing in mind that I wrote a multi-line example for readability but the HTML code I intend on using it is all glued on one line or at least there are several different tags on the same line)

Comment: those are multi lines properly idented files. I'm guessing I also need to disregard the linefeeds differences, good point

Comment: If your real data has multiple lines then make sure the example you provide in your question for us to test with has multiple lines. Make sure your example covers the worst case, not just the trivial sunny-day case, so you get an answer that handles it. Also tell us if you are using or can use GNU awk (`awk --version` will tell you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
ARGIND == 1 { old=$0 }
ARGIND == 2 { new=$0 }
ARGIND == 3 {
    if ( s = index($0,old) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))
    }
    print
}
' oldImage.svg newImage.svg file.html
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND, if you don't have that add a line at the top that says:

```
FNR == 1 { ARGIND++ }
```

Comment: You'd just have to set `-v RS='^$'` or similar to handle multi-line data but that's not what the OP showed in their example and they said in the question they were operating with `single line ... files`.

Comment: Ah, I see, well if/when the OP posts a more truly representative example I'll update my answer to match. It'll be trivial to tweak but there's a couple of things to consider (e.g. is there only 1 replacement per line or per file or...?) and I don't want to do it without a concrete example to test against.

Comment: it was fairly easy to adapt both svg files to single line files (I didn't know if I needed it as I've changed them before realising macOS awk isn't gawk and I needed the extra line at top). I did a quick bask for loop to cycle through the html files, backing them and piping the printed result over the original file. thanks